# How to pass value from the main program to a Class in C#

Tags: c#

Please help, am stuck on connecting variables in the class and those in the main program. Am trying to get values from users and storing those values in the class for further processing. When I try to use a class constructor with parameters its not working. Here is my code. Thank you in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SkrlPrototype
{
public class  DieCast
{
    private int _Machine1 { get; set; }
    private int _Machine2 { get; set; }
    private int _Machine3 { get; set; }
    private int _Machine4 { get; set; }
    private int _Machine5 { get; set; }
    private int _Machine7 { get; set; }
    private int _Machine8 { get; set; }
    private int _Machine10 { get; set; }
    private int _Machine12 { get; set; }

    public int GoodPieces;
    public int Scrap;
    public int Shots;

    public DieCast(int Machine1, int Machine2, int Machine3, int Machine4, int    Machine5, int Machine7, int Machine8, int Machine10, int Machine12)//I tried to create a constructor in order to pass value to the variables in a class for further calculation, but couldn't
    {
        _Machine1 = Machine1;
        _Machine2 = Machine2;
        _Machine3 = Machine3;
        _Machine4 = Machine4;
        _Machine5 = Machine5;
        _Machine7 = Machine7;
        _Machine8 = Machine8;
        _Machine10 = Machine10;
        _Machine12 = Machine12;
    }

    int[] Machine;

    public static void bestOperatorAccordingToShots()
    { 

      //To do        
    }

    public static void bestOperatorAccordingToGoodPieces()
    {
           //To do
    }

    public static void worstOperatorAccordingToShot()
    {
            //To do
    }

    public static void worstOperatorAccordingToScrap()
    {
           //To do
    }

    public static void AllGoodPieces()
    {      
     //To do        
    }

    public static void AllScrap()
    {
                //To do

    }

    public static void AllShots()
    {
              //To do
    }

    public static void display()
    {
                 //To do
    }
}
}

///////////////////////////////My main program///////////////////
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace kessPrototype
{
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
{

        int _machine1;
        int _machine2;
        int _machine3;
        int _machine4;
        int _machine5;
        int _machine7;
        int _machine8;
        int _machine10;
        int _machine12;
        DieCast die = new DieCast(_machine1, _machine2, _machine3, _machine4, _machine5, _machine7, _machine8, _machine10, _machine12)
        {
            //_Machine1=Machine1;
            //_Machine2=Machine2;
            // _Machine3=Machine3;
            // _Machine4=Machine4;
            // _Machine5=Machine5;
            // _Machine7=Machine7;
            // _Machine8=Machine8;
            // _Machine10=Machine10;
            // _Machine12=Machine12;

          //This is where the problem is. I couldn't pass value to the class


        };
        Console.Write("Please enter Machine1");
        _machine1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Please enter Machine2");
        _machine2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Please enter Machine3");
        _machine3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Please enter Machine4");
        _machine4 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Please enter Machine5");
        _machine5 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Please enter Machine7");
        _machine7 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Please enter Machine8");
        _machine8 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Please enter Machine10");
        _machine10 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Please enter Machine12");
        _machine12 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("press any key to close");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Move the creation of the die instance after the input, then pass the values to the constructor of DieCast

Comment: Create your object AFTER reading values from a user.

Answer (score -1):

You should initialize your machines before passing them to the constructor. Then, you don't need to redefine your constructor when using `new`.

Try that :

```
int _machine1, _machine2; //...

Console.Write("Please enter Machine1");
_machine1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //...

DieCast die = new DieCast(_machine1, _machine2, _machine3, _machine4, _machine5, _machine7, _machine8, _machine10, _machine12);
```

Comment: All right, now to have an answer with something more than the comments above, imagine a very stupid user that instead of typing a number types a series of letters "ABC".

Comment: @Steve Sorry, I didn't saw the comments above while I was typing my answer. I think he can do it on his own, with TryParse() for example.

Comment: You may need to use [`Int32.TryParse Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)